# Cannot set custom request header on ajax calls from my local developing server

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

Im trying to set a local dev js client to call my remote server that serves a REST API. My server is fully functional and tested. When I try to execute javascript locally I cannot set custom headers. Im aware of the cross domain policy, and to fix that im executing chrome using **--disable-web-security** to allow cross domain calls. The calls are actually going, but when I check the request header there is no trace of my custom headers.

Im setting two headers in my DEV server using jQuery exactly as im setting them in production:

```
        var ajaxOptions = {
            ajax: {
                headers: { 'X-App-Key': appKey, 'X-Auth-Token': token },
                //and some other stuff
```

My API respond with and error telling me that a header is missing, and checking the console I cant see it any where:
[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, struggling with this now, and it appears that there is no way to set a custom header for a cross domain ajax request unless you have CORS set up on the server. Custom headers trigger a preflight request, see here http://techblog.constantcontact.com/software-development/using-cors-for-cross-domain-ajax-requests/